# Spring Security - Is there another way to intercept urls

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-security

So guys, there is a way to intercept urls, preventing non-logged users to acess, using spring security, but not at xml config or java based, something like @PreAuthorize on methods, and these ones return a view after they done something, but not like actions (add, delete).

Something like these:

```
 @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated")
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home()
{
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: Where else would you want to do that? That's why configurations are there for.

Comment: Like example, I think it would be more dynamic if you could annotate your method and it gets the url then intercept it.

Comment: If I can do only at config file it's OK then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is possible, but it's less performance efficient  and scatters the security code all over the controllers. To see the full capabilities of Expression-Based Access Control, check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access) documentation